# Make a vector positive

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, hadamard-product

I have some vectors, which I want to make positive, like taking the absolute value of each element.
The vector should be differentiable, so I cannot use some kind of abs-value.
I'm looking for the mathematical expression to do this.

I thought about taking the square-root of the hadamard product of the vector.
$$
c = (\sqrt{(A \odot A})^T ) \cdot (B \odot B)
$$

How would the differential $$\frac{dc}{dA}$$ looks like?

Edit:
The Matlab execution is:

```
c = sqrt(A.^2)'*B.^2
```

Comment: By "make positive" do you mean make the entries into positive numbers? By "vector should be differentiable," do you mean the output is a differentiable function of the input? If so, first do it for $n=1$ and use that function componentwise. (Use trig functions.) It's not clear to me in your idea what $A$ and $B$ are. (Is one of them the input vector? If so, how are you taking the square root of a vector?)

Comment: A is an input Force vector (with positive and negative forces), B is an output displacement vector (positive and negative displacements), c can be seen as the compliance value, summed over de n dimensions of A and B (F and U). A negative Force component and a corresponding positive Displacement will result in a negative compliance term. Hence, I want these individual compliance term summed as positive components.

Answer (score 1):

Let's consider a one-dimensiona vector, then $$c = \sqrt{A^2}B^2=B^2|A|$$

Hence it is not differentiable.

However, if you consider

$$
c = ((A \odot A)^T ) \cdot (B \odot B) = \sum_{i=1}^n (B_iA_i)^2
$$
$$\frac{dc}{dA}=2A \odot (B \odot B)$$

Edit:

To preserve the magnitude of $A$, let's consider the following approximation, consider approximating $\sqrt{x^2}$ with $\sqrt{x^2+\epsilon}$.

[image]
If we were to use

$$c=\sum_{i=1}^n\sqrt{A_i^2+\epsilon}B_i^2$$

$$\frac{dc}{dA_i}=\frac{A_i}{\sqrt{A_i^2+\epsilon}}B_i^2$$

The Matlab execution for $\frac{dc}{dA}$ would be

```
(A./(A.^2+ epsilon)).* B.^2
```

Comment: Thanks,
You skipped the square root, but this is absolutely essential for my problem. The differential you displayed is good; however, I want the terms of A to be scaled down (since these are squared). In my particular case it means a force value below 1 will become very small, and a value above 1 will become very big. Due to further calculation, I cannot skip the scaling down.

Comment: Edited to propose a heuristic.

Comment: Can we use this approximation to calculate the differential dc/dA?

Comment: what is your current $C$ function now?

Comment: C is the c from my first post, added a Matlab execution for clarification

Comment: so we are applying the square root approximation elementwise right? and you intentionally want to square the $B$ vector elementwise right?

Comment: Yes, right, basically we want to calculate the abs(A) times the B^2, both vectors

Comment: Edited the post for the new $c$. The initial $c$ that you propose is not differentiable. Note that $\sqrt{x^2}=|x|$.